# How to best catch sleep and resume events for OSX?

Tags: python, macos, bash, osx-yosemite

I want to make a timer that counts whenever the system (Mac OS X Yosemite) is on. My idea is to use python and listen for sleep and resume signals and increment a counter whenever the system is on. However, I haven't been able to find much information on how to do this.

1. Would it be feasible to go about this problem with what I have detailed?
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `uptime` and `sysctl -a | grep sleeptime` to help in this process. It isn't a python solution but you could always shell out to it if you wanted to use python for some parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using PyObjC (which should be installed by default on Yosemite, or perhaps after installing Xcode):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from AppKit import NSWorkspace, NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification, \
                   NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification, NSObject, \
                   NSApplication, NSLog

class App(NSObject):

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
        workspace          = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
        notificationCenter = workspace.notificationCenter()
        notificationCenter.addObserver_selector_name_object_(
            self,
            self.receiveSleepNotification_,
            NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification,
            None
        )
        notificationCenter.addObserver_selector_name_object_(
            self,
            self.receiveWakeNotification_,
            NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification,
            None
        )

    def receiveSleepNotification_(self, notification):
        NSLog("receiveSleepNotification: %@", notification)

    def receiveWakeNotification_(self, notification):
        NSLog("receiveWakeNotification: %@", notification)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sharedapp = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    app       = App.alloc().init()
    sharedapp.setDelegate_(app)
    sharedapp.run()
```

(Based on [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html))